# Average per fund and customer needed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I calculate the average fund balance of a customer who might have funds across a number of funds?

For example member 32 has just a fund_balance of 42515.4452
But for member 428 I would want to return (2400.6078 + 8317.434)/2 = 5359.021
For member 1214, I need (2043.6056 + 3110.9399 +15596.3102 )/ 3 = 681.2019

I tried the following, not sure what I did wrong?

```
SELECT [dim_member_key], 
       AVG(fund_balance) OVER(PARTITION BY fund_code) AS AvgAmount
FROM #test;
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't use images for data, use tabular text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this per customer, then that should be the `partition by` key:

```
SELECT dim_member_key, 
       AVG(fund_balance) OVER (PARTITION BY dim_member_key) AS AvgAmount
FROM #test;
```

You can get the same information more concisely using aggregation:

```
SELECT dim_member_key, 
       AVG(fund_balance) OVER (PARTITION BY dim_member_key) AS AvgAmount
FROM #test
GROUP BY dim_member_key;
```

Comment: Cool, that is right, when I wrote it I just thought I nee to partition by the member. :-) Thanks a lot